# Form redirection to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my website, I have a listing page.

It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV1lk.png)

The part on the left is a form, and I want the user to be redirected to an updated listing page with his choice (example on the picture, Project for sale and project for sale.)
So basically, the user makes his choice and then clicks submit. The user is then redirected to a page that is similar, with only the projects of this type. There is 4 different options the user can select:

- Project for sale and in the past
- project for sale and happening right now
- Project for rent and in the past
- Project for rent and happening right now

This is the code I wrote:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.button-submit').click(function(){
         var radioValue = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();

         if ((radioValue == 'vente') || (radioValue == 'passe')){
              window.location.href = 'page1.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'vente') || (radioValue == 'present')) {
              window.location.href = 'page2.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'location') || (radioValue == 'passe')){
              window.location.href = 'page3.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'location') || (radioValue == 'present')){
              window.location.href = 'page4.com';
         }
    })
});
```

For some reason, I can't get my code to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <div class="w-form">
      <form id="wf-form-Choice-form" name="wf-form-Choice-form" data-name="Choice form">
        <h2 class="h2-big titreprojet"><strong>Découvrez NoTRE PORTFOLIO</strong><br></h2>
        <div class="lineprojet"></div>
        <div class="description">Notre caractère distinctif, c’est d’avoir réalisé des projets de qualité, tout en procurant une expérience unique à nos clients. <br></div>
        <div class="w-row">
          <div class="column-16 w-col w-col-6">
            <div class="smalltext">Type de projet</div><label class="radio-button-field-2 w-radio"><input type="radio" data-name="Typedeprojet" id="vente" name="Typedeprojet" value="vente" class="w-form-formradioinput projetenvente w-radio-input"><span for="vente" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projets en vente</span></label><label class="radio-button-field-3 w-radio"><input type="radio" data-name="Typedeprojet" id="location" value="location" name="Typedeprojet" class="w-form-formradioinput projetenlocation w-radio-input"><span for="location" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projets en location</span></label></div>
          <div class="w-col w-col-6">
            <div class="smalltext">DATE DU PROJET</div><label class="radio-button-field-5 w-radio"><input type="radio" data-name="Timeline" id="actuel" name="Timeline" value="actuel" class="w-form-formradioinput projetactuel w-radio-input"><span for="actuel" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projet actuel</span></label><label class="radio-button-field-4 w-radio"><input type="radio" data-name="Timeline" id="passe" name="Timeline" value="passe" class="w-form-formradioinput projetpasse w-radio-input"><span for="passe" class="textcheck w-form-label">Projets passé</span></label></div>
        </div><a href="#" class="button filter w-button">Recherchez</a></form>
      <div class="w-form-done">
        <div>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="w-form-fail">
        <div>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show the relative html. Specially the form. I believe the form is being submitted that you need to prevent.

Comment: Instead of `||` you need `&&`

Comment: I use a CMS called webflow. This is the html link:

https://habitat-df.webflow.io/site-web/nos-realisations

Editing question with html

Comment: what happens when you click on submit? Nothing? Or is there a error in the console? if there is no error, try logging what is in 'radioValue' - if only to prove that the click event is wired up.

Comment: Yeah same question. The HTML part will be pretty important here as we can't see radio values and we don't know if button type is submit and some behaviours need to be prevented or not as @NawedKhan mentioned.

Comment: Just as a side comment. the actual purpose of radio buttons is to be able to have only one selected value, in the image you posted there are two selected values, that is what checkboxes are supposed to do.

Comment: @JenaroCalviño so using checkbox is more adequate in this case? I will remake it using checkboxes.

Comment: There is no 'button-submit' in your html. Please explain what is happening and what is not working. From the code in question nothing should work.

Comment: @Kyle nothing happens

Comment: I believe so, check the definition of radio buttons here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your page just reloads once you submit the form. 
You don't use `preventDefault()` when submitting your form.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.button-submit').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var radioValue = jQuery('input:radio:checked').val();

         if ((radioValue == 'vente') || (radioValue == 'passe')){
              window.location.href = 'page1.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'vente') || (radioValue == 'present')) {
              window.location.href = 'page2.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'location') || (radioValue == 'passe')){
              window.location.href = 'page3.com';
         }
         if ((radioValue == 'location') || (radioValue == 'present')){
              window.location.href = 'page4.com';
         }
    })
});
```

Also I would suggest you to listen once your form is submitted instead of button click: `$("#form").on("submit", function(e) {...})`